# How to Get SHA1 fingerprint key in Win 8.1?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to use Google Maps API and for that i am trying to get SHA1 figerprint key. I have seen many tutorials but couldn't get the desired result. Here is what i am getting:
[image]

Comment: I am using **Android Studio**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting your path C:\Users...blablabla...debug.keystore. in double quotes

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\Muhammad Ali Ansari\.android\debug.keystore"
```